# Strange checkbox click function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click, datatables

Using datatables. The problem is `$('.checkbox')` click function only works on first page of datatables, nowhere else. Note that, `$('#check_all')` works on every page.

JS looks like that:

```
function changeQt(){
    if($('#quantity').is(':hidden'))            
        $('#quantity').fadeIn("slow");
    $('#quantity').animate({
        borderColor: "#00a9e0"
    }, 'fast').text(totalqt).delay(400).animate({
        borderColor: "#fff"
    }, 'fast');    
    
    
}

function doIt(obj) {
    if ($(obj).is(":checked")) {
        $(obj).closest("tr").not('#hdr').addClass("row_selected");
        totalqt=totalqt + parseInt($(obj).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);        
    }
    else {
        $(obj).closest("tr").not('#hdr').removeClass("row_selected");
        totalqt=totalqt - parseInt($(obj).closest("tr").find("#qt").text(), 10);
        if(totalqt<0) totalqt=0;
    }
}



function checkAllCheckboxes(isChecked) { 
    if(isChecked ){ 
        totalqt=0; 
    } 
    $('.checkbox').each(function(){ 
        $(this).prop('checked', isChecked); 
        doIt(this); 
    }); 
    changeQt(); 
} 

$(document).delegate('td.item_id', 'click', function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
}); 
$(document).delegate('#list > tbody > tr', 'click', function(){ 
    window.open($(this).attr("url")); 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:submit, input:reset").button();
    $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
        
    $('select[name=list_length]').change(function(){
        if ($('#check_all').is(':checked'))
            $('#check_all').click();   
    });

    var oTable= $('#list').dataTable( {       
        "bJQueryUI": true, 
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aoColumns": [ 
        {
            "bSortable": false
        },
        null, null, null,null,null, null, null
        ]    
    } ).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [    null, null, null,null,null, null, null,
        {
            type: "date-range"
        }
        ]

    });
    

    
    $('.checkbox').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        doIt(this);
        changeQt()
       
    });
     
    $('select[name=list_length]').change(function(){ 
        if($('#check_all').is(':checked')){ 
            $('#check_all').prop('checked', false); 
            checkAllCheckboxes(false); 
        } 
    }); 

    $('#check_all').click(function(){ 
        checkAllCheckboxes(this.checked); 
    }); 
 });
```

Here is 1 row from this table:

```
<tr url="?page=item&id=1411">

<td class="item_id"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" method="post" value="1411" class="checkbox"/>    1411</td>
<td> 9814</td>
<td style="text-align:center">BK</td>
<td style="text-align:center">36</td>
<td style="text-align:center" id="qt">1</td>
<td style="text-align:center">15</td>
<td style="text-align:center">12</td>
<td>15.02.2012</td>

</tr>
```

If someone want to see page in action, please join discussion: [**Here**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7749/strange-issue-with-click-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume dataTables is adding/removing elements from the DOM, and with them will go the event handlers attached to them.

Instead of attaching events by the shortcuts (eg `click()`, or `blur()`) which will only work when the element in question is available on page load, use `delegate()` (or `on()` in jQuery 1.7+)

```
$("#list").delegate('.checkbox', 'click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    doIt(this);
    changeQt()
});
```

jQ 1.7+

```
$("#list").on('click', '.checkbox', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    doIt(this);
    changeQt()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ about events will be of some use to you here: http://datatables.net/faqs#events . It also includes examples of how to apply the solution. In this case I would suggest using:

```
table.$('.checkbox').click(function(e) {
```

where table is the DataTables instance. The $ API method will give you a jQuery object that will operate on all rows in the table, regardless of current paging.